# Power BI compare dates

Tags: powerbi, dax

I am new with power BI and need your help.

I have 3 columns which are:

1. date1
2. reviseDate
3. Shipped_Date

I need to compare column `reviseDate` to `shipped_date` if it is <> or =.

How to I do it, if `reviseDate` column is blank, must refer on column `Date1` to compare with `shipped_Date` column?

[image: Desired output]

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can define a new [calculated column](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/power-bi/desktop-tutorial-create-calculated-columns) like this:

```
Status = IF (AND(ISBLANK(Table1[Date1]); ISBLANK(Table1[ReviseDate])); BLANK();
    IF (Table1[Shipped_Date] = IF(ISBLANK(Table1[ReviseDate]); Table1[Date1]; Table1[ReviseDate]); "On Time";
        IF (Table1[Shipped_Date] > IF(ISBLANK(Table1[ReviseDate]); Table1[Date1]; Table1[ReviseDate]); "Late";
            IF (Table1[Shipped_Date] < IF(ISBLANK(Table1[ReviseDate]); Table1[Date1]; Table1[ReviseDate]); "Early"; BLANK())
        )
    )
)
```

The expression `IF(ISBLANK(Table1[ReviseDate]); Table1[Date1]; Table1[ReviseDate])` will return `Date1` value in case `ReviseDate` is empty. Then it is matter of comparing this reference date with `Shipped_Date` and returning appropriate status.

[image]

If you want to make status column using Power Query Editor, you can use `Add Column` -> `Conditional Column`. Make one helper column, named `ReferenceDate` or something, which will compute the date we need to use for comparison:

[image]

Then add the actual `Status` column like this:

[image]

The M code will look like this (the data is embedded in it):

```
let
    Source = Table.FromRows(Json.Document(Binary.Decompress(Binary.FromText("bY7RCQAhDEN36bcUUxTrLOL+aygenCkI/WjymtAxxKp2tQyXJHuunGnDFmFj+HldAQqUGzC89nPlsdYZuiITrL98PRRqQUkYCyqZCw==", BinaryEncoding.Base64), Compression.Deflate)), let _t = ((type text) meta [Serialized.Text = true]) in type table [Date1 = _t, ReviseDate = _t, Shipped_Date = _t]),
    #"Changed Type" = Table.TransformColumnTypes(Source,{{"Date1", type date}, {"ReviseDate", type date}, {"Shipped_Date", type date}}),
    #"Added Conditional Column" = Table.AddColumn(#"Changed Type", "ReferenceDate", each if [ReviseDate] = null then [Date1] else [ReviseDate]),
    #"Added Conditional Column1" = Table.AddColumn(#"Added Conditional Column", "Status", each if [ReferenceDate] = null then "" else if [ReferenceDate] = [Shipped_Date] then "On Time" else if [ReferenceDate] < [Shipped_Date] then "Late" else if [ReferenceDate] > [Shipped_Date] then "Early" else null),
    Status = #"Added Conditional Column1"{2}[Status]
in
    Status
```

Depending on your data source, you can even modify the query and retrieve this value from the database (e.g. with Transact-SQL query if your data source is SQL Server).

Answer (score 4):

Try this as a calculated column:

```
Status = 
VAR DueDate =
    IF(ISBLANK(Table1[Revised]), [Date1], [Revised])
RETURN
    SWITCH(
        TRUE(),
        ISBLANK(DueDate), BLANK(),
        DueDate = Table1[Shipped_Date], "On Time",
        DueDate < Table1[Shipped_Date], "Late",
        DueDate > Table1[Shipped_Date], "Early"
    )
```

This defines the date you want to compare as a variable that we use to check different conditions.

The `SWITCH(TRUE(),...)` is a [useful construction](https://powerpivotpro.com/2015/03/the-diabolical-genius-of-switch-true/) that returns the specified result for the first condition in the list that evaluates to `TRUE()`.